# c#: enumeration yielded no result

Tags: c#, linq, exception, var

Im setting value in a variable like this:

```
var billing = context.Payload.QuestionGroupList.Where(x => x.GroupCode.ToLower().Equals("yourinfo"));
```

But problem is, I get null exception when I query it. Although I have kept a null check but it passes this check and when I expand the resultview I see 'enumeration yielded no result'

I get NULL reference exception since `billing` is empty on the following line. So my question is what further check I can apply to avoid it?

```
if (billing != null)
{
   billingAddress = billing.FirstOrDefault().QuestionList.Where(x => x.Code.ToLower().Equals("billingaddressques")).Select(x => new Question { QuestionAnswer = x.QuestionAnswer, Code = x.Code }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: `billing.FirstOrDefault()` could return `null` aswell. Remember this a linq query on an enumeration never returns `null`. Like where/select/orderby etc.. if there is nothing, it returns an empty enumeration.

Comment: @J.vanLangen what check should be added other than `(billing != null)` to avoid null?

Comment: You should check to see if `billing` contains any items as well as the null check:     `if (billing != null && billing.Any())`

Comment: What about `QuestionList`, `x.Code`, etc?

Comment: @HumaAli `billing.Any()` does the right job. If you use `FirstOrDefault` always check if it return the default. for classes is it `null`

Comment: @PatrickHofman assumtions ofcourse, but it looks like a detail table. which probably is created by the db framework

Comment: They can be null. @J.vanLangen

Comment: @PatrickHofman never worked with it, but I wouldn't program it that way... ;-)  an empty collection is way different than a `null`